# PHP - Multi DB Connection suddenly not working

Tags: php, mysql, connection

I have 2 databases:

- news_db. having table : t_news
- branding. having table : t_branding

I have db connection:

```
$con1 = mysql_connect('127.1.0.0', 'root', 'root'); 
mysql_select_db('news_db', $con1);

$con2 = mysql_connect('127.1.0.0', 'root', 'root'); 
mysql_select_db('branding', $con2);
```

My codes:

```
$dataNews = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_news",$con1));
echo $dataNews['title']; /* it is working, showing "Test Title" */

$dataBrand = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_branding",$con2));
echo $dataBrand['title']; /* it is not working, nothing to show */
```

But if i reverse the query like :

```
$dataBrand = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_branding",$con2));
echo $dataBrand['title']; /* it is working, showing "Test Brand Title */

$dataNews = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_news",$con1));
echo $dataNews['title']; /* it is not working, nothing to show" */
```

Can anybody help me, why the sudden php and mysql as though I can only run one connection, but yesterday all of connections can walk and coding nothing has changed. Thanks

Comment: Check the results of `mysql_error`. May I also recommend finally getting rid of `mysql` extension? )

Comment: Shouldn't `127.1.0.0` be `127.0.0.1` ? Edit: Don't worry still points to localhost apparently. Learn something new everyday.

Comment: Have you changed anything in your database structure? Database name/table name or column name?

Comment: @raina77ow : no error showing.

Comment: @Darren : The IP Purposely changed from 127.0.0.1 to 127.1.0.0 by network operator

Comment: @sectus : can you explain me, how do you mean?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek : I has been checked all DB, Structure, Data, Procedure all fine, nothing changed.

Comment: @Fredy what @sectus means is `mysql_` is being deprecated. It is recommended to switch to `mysqli_`.

Comment: I have contacted my system admin, it turns out there was nothing wrong with my code, it turns out the system admin set up a connection to the database is only allowed once per user, to connect to the second database must use a user account other than the first. By this I assume the question / problem has been resolved. Thank you all

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that you're reusing the connection:

Taken from the manual for [`mysql_connect()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php):

> If a second call is made to mysql_connect() with the same arguments,
> no new link will be established, but instead, the link identifier of
> the already opened link will be returned. The new_link parameter
> modifies this behavior and makes mysql_connect() always open a new
> link, even if mysql_connect() was called before with the same
> parameters. In SQL safe mode, this parameter is ignored.

You should parse the fourth (*`true`* which is **`$new_link`**) parameter to the second connect like below:

```
$con1 = mysql_connect('127.1.0.0', 'root', 'root'); 
mysql_select_db('news_db', $con1);

$con2 = mysql_connect('127.1.0.0', 'root', 'root', true); 
mysql_select_db('branding', $con2);
```

---

As stated, you should avoid using `mysql_*` functions as the api **IS** depreciated.
Alternatively you should be looking into [**`PDO`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [**`Mysqli Prepared Statements`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

**Some More Notes**

You should turn on error reporting when developing to ensure you don't run into any issues:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

And since you're using mysql, you should look at `mysql_error()` which probably would've thrown a message something like:

```
The table TABLENAME doesn't exist in DATABASE
```

Answer (score 2):

With the code-

```
$con1 = mysql_connect('127.1.0.0', 'root', 'root'); 
mysql_select_db('news_db', $con1);

$con2 = mysql_connect('127.1.0.0', 'root', 'root'); 
mysql_select_db('branding', $con2);
```

Or,

```
$con1 = mysql_connect('127.1.0.0', 'root', 'root'); 
$con2 = mysql_connect('127.1.0.0', 'root', 'root'); // this line is redundant, both lines are same

mysql_select_db('news_db', $con1);
mysql_select_db('branding', $con2); // this will be selected
```

the effect will be that- the database **branding** will be selected, **news_db** wont be selected, coz its written after `news_db`!

So, your bnoth the queries will look for the database **branding** and will throw error "*Table ...... not found*" if you check with `mysql_error()`

Answer (score 1):

```
$con1 = mysql_connect('127.1.0.0', 'root', 'root'); 
mysql_select_db('news_db', $con1);


$dataNews = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_news",$con1));
echo $dataNews['name'];

$con2 = mysql_connect('127.1.0.0', 'root', 'root'); 
mysql_select_db('branding', $con2);
$dataBrand = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_branding",$con2));
echo $dataBrand['title'];
```

You can use this code.I think it will be helpful for you.